# audio content type aacp

Tags: html, audio, streaming, content-type

I have a problem with audio tag, that is that I'm trying to listen to a radio, but it doesn't work. I have this:

```
<audio src="http://www.musicgoal.es/internet-radio/stream/1000057711/default.m3u?34098542444009535e54e4af54933128" id="audioPlayer">
</audio>
```

The content type is **aacp** and I read in internet that the problem is due to this type.

Anyone can give me a solution for this?

Maybe, I need to decode, right?

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems.  The first is that you are trying to load a playlist instead of the audio stream itself.  If you hit that URL with cURL or wget, you will notice that the real stream URL is:

- http://sc1.flobbo.de:8128/stream/4/

Your second problem is that not all browsers can decode aacPlus.  You will need to get a differently encoded streams for browsers that cannot decode it.